# Windows 7 Laptop unable to recognize Samsung GT-S7562 and Micrommax A116 Android Device

Tags: samsung, windows, usb-drivers

I have two Android phones: a Micromax A116 and a Samsung GT-S7562.

I am able to connect both of the devices on an XP Machine at the office. But at home I have a laptop running Windows 7. When I try to connect it, both of the phones are not getting detected.

I have installed Samsung Kies for GT-S7562 and I have also installed the Micromax A116 drivers on both XP and Windows 7.

I also tried uninstalling and reinstalling all the drivers. But no use.

I need help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: How many USB slots do you have? Have you tried moving the data cable to those slots?

Comment: It has 3 USB slots. Yes I have tried in all the slots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any android phone can be easily detected based on the purpose of connection.Just check and ensure the type of USB driver you download is for the correct purpose.

Basically we have two modes of connecting an Android device to a system.

1.As a Personal user(can be any,file transfer,update,backup etc.)

2.As a Developer(to debug,deploy an application etc.)

1.**As a personal user**
If you basically want to connect your device for personal use.Then you need the simple USB drivers which can be downloaded from Samsung.Depending on your Operating system you need to install the required file.For [Samsung](http://www.samsung.com/us/support/downloads).Contact micromax for the USB drivers as i didn't find any.

**Ex**:-If you have a windows 7 Operating system then it will automatically download and install the USB drivers and if it's Linux then you need to search for the respective drivers regarding Linux and install based on your procedure.But if it's Windows XP then you need to manually search for the USB driver's download it and install them  as and where required.Once installed you can connect your device and do your work

**2.As a Developer**:-If you need to connect the android phone as a developer/tester then you need to download the special ADB debug drivers.These drivers are way different from the normal U.S.B drivers as they provide you to test/debug the application on the device but not for file transfer or any other use.
After downloading manually or automatically from the SDK Manager you can connect your device but you need to configure it .Check this [site](http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/oem-usb.html) for more details.Once done your device will be detected by the eclipse software and then you can do you work.

Based on the use of yours you can select the choice of connection.

**Note**:-The basic connection setup is the same for all the devices irrespective of their manufacturer.Although there may/may not be any slight changes based on the Android Version.

The difference is may be you have restrictions/U.S.B drivers are missing in Windows XP machine.So just check whether the U.S.B drivers are not disabled and you have access to the U.S.B as well

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried going to device manager and right-clicking the top of the tree and selecting "Detect Hardware Changes"? Maybe your "Shell Hardware Detection" service isn't running or not running right?

Or are there any exceptions on the USB controllers of the system in your device manager?

Comment: Yes I have tried these things.